# What method is the easiest/fastest way for developing Android Apps

Tags: android

Which one of these is the easiest/fastest choice for developing simple Android apps/games? I'm familiar with all of these technologies.

- Android SDK or NDK
- C# on MonoDroid platform
- Adobe Flash & Adobe AIR
- Corona SDK
- Converting tools like PhoneGap

Fundamentally, Could you explain adventages and disadventages of this methods.

Comment: If you are familiar with all of these technologies then you are probably the best person to answer the question!

Answer (score 2):

I would say the the easiest may not always be the best!  If you're looking to make games I would suggest using C++ with the Android NDK.  If you're looking to make apps the way that would give you the most control is going to be using the SDK.  If you have an existing web app you can use PhoneGap or Air.  It's all about picking the right tool for the job but for 99% of all cases I would say your best bet is to use the SDK.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **it depends**. It depends on what you can write applications fastest with in general, and what the requirements for the particular app are.